# Run SQL script in MySQLWorkbench fails with UTF8 encoded script

Tags: utf-8, mysql-workbench

I'm using the latest (8.0.33) version of MySQLWorkbench on macOS Ventura 13.3.1 (a).

When trying to run a SQL script via "`File/Run SQL Script...`" I get the following error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 109: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is correct in that the script is encoded in UTF8 (w/o BOM) because it contains special characters such as umlauts.
How can I tell MySQLWorkbench to open the file with UTF8 encoding. I haven't found any setting regarding this.